# CPU usage event notification in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, cpu, cpu-usage, system-calls

Having a hard time finding if there's a system call to receive a notification when the CPU usage reaches a certain point? I'm specifically looking for a call for Linux/BSD variants, but if you know the Windows version chime in as well so I know for future reference.

Something similar to kqueue.

Obviously I could just check out /proc/cpuinfo or the individual utimes periodically, but I was hoping there was a system call that would do it for me in a more efficient way.

e.g. "Let me know when the average total CPU usage over the last minute is over 50%"

Answer (score 1):

You can get CPU usage information from `getrusage()` and you can use *soft* limits with `setrlimit()` to get `SIGXCPU` when you exceed a preset threshold (which you can then increase in the signal handler).

More information:  http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl2_getrusage.htm

Comment: I've used this before, but then I'd have continuously poll this in a loop until (or if) the usage passed the threshold, where as with kqueue the kernel handles keeping track of things and it doesn't return until the event is triggered. I need to be constantly notified every time the threshold is past.

Answer (score 0):

The APIs you're looking for are GetProcessTimes and GetSystemTimes. [This link](http://www.philosophicalgeek.com/2009/01/03/determine-cpu-usage-of-current-process-c-and-c/) has two very good examples of using them. If you have any further questions, since I've used them myself to determine the CPUUsage, feel free to ask.

Comment: I've used this before, but then I'd have continuously poll this in a loop until (or if) the usage passed the threshold, where as with kqueue the kernel handles keeping track of things and it doesn't return until the event is triggered. I need to be constantly notified every time the threshold is past.